# Need Some Advice on How to Plot My Scientific Data

Tags: data-visualization

I have a project where I am running water through very small diameter tubes and I am trying to show for this plot that if you double the pressure that you double the flow rate out of these capillaries. The thing is though that I have different diameter tubes that I have tested this relationship for, so I am trying to compare three variables. I have to show that if you double the pressure and keep the diameter constant your flow rate doubles, and I have different diameters to show that this is true. How do I make an elegant graph that compares these three variables?

Comment: Can you post your data (or a small sample of them) for people to work with?

Comment: Sure, give me a sec

Comment: That's a long second. Can you post any data?

Comment: Haha sorry for the delay, I decided to plot the Data as ratio of flow rates vs. Diameter. A correlation of 2 shows that it is linear, and I am happy with the results so I don't need any more help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on what you want to show with your plots. In engineering generally, and fluid mechanics in particular, it is quite common to collapse different parameters using [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis).

For example in your case ([Poiseuille flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation), similar to [Darcy flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%27s_law)) you could show that, "other things being equal"* the relation
$$\frac{Q}{Pd^4}=\text{constant}$$
holds, where $Q$ is flow rate, $P$ is applied ([differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_measurement#Absolute.2C_gauge_and_differential_pressures_.E2.80.94_zero_reference)) pressure, and $d$ is diameter.

(*where "other things" = outflow pressure, flow length, and viscosity.)

---

If you expand on the details of your data and on what you want to show, I can give more specific suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

1. I'd suggest plotting on the log scale for all variables -- specifically, I'd plot log(flow rate) on the y-axis vs log(pressure) on the x-axis
2. I'd use colours for the different diameters (or some other way to distinguish them)
3. I'd plot background lines (in grey, say) of slope 1 so that it would be easy to see if the points of a given colour tended to lie close to the expected slope for the stated relationship.